# Quicksight - Lookup value based on running total of another column

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I want to create a calculated field in AWS QuickSight where I have look at the input date and calculate a running total (in ascending order of date) and look up the date where total cost = $3.

example, For A, the running total on 1/2 = $1, running total on 1/3 = $1 + $2 = $3

Input

| Vendor. | Date | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A. | 1/2 | $1 |
| A. | 1/3 | $2. |
| A. | 1/4 | $1. |
| B. | 1/2 | $3 |
| B. | 1/3 | $2. |
| B. | 1/4 | $1. |

Output

| Vendor. | Date | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A. | 1/3 | $3 |
| B. | 1/2 | $3. |

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [runningSum](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/runningSum-function.html) and a filter on the calculated field created by it.

Assuming your cost column doesn't have the dollar sign at the start. You can create a calculated field like the following

```
runningSum
(
  SUM({Cost}) 
  ,[ {Date} ASC ]  
  ,[ {Vendor} ] 
)
```

In your analysis you can then create a filter where RunningSum equals 3 (like in your example provided), include the date in the visual and it should show the values that you are looking for.

If your cost column does have the dollar sign then you can use something like [replace](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/replace-function.html) or [substring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/substring-function.html) to create a calculated field to represent just the integer part